# Query returns different results between PL/SQL Developer and PHP

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have made a small intranet website to collect and store data to be used to expedite our logistics processes. I'm now in the process of adding search functionality which, if records are found that match that criteria, will allow the user to quickly select parts of that data to pre-populate a new shipping request with data (e.g, the user types 'Mar' in the Recipient Name input textbox and '109' in the Street Address input textbox and the query returns two records: {"Mary Smith", "1090 South Central St"} and {"Mark Swanson", "109 E. 31st St."}).

At the moment, when search criteria is entered and submitted, the data returned from the query in PHP is 100% accurate if and only if a single criteria is entered (such as Recipient Name). When I attempt to use two different search criterias in PHP, the record results do not match the results when running the same query in Oracle PL/SQL Developer. If three different search criterias are used, the query ran in PHP will return 0 records. In all three of the aforementioned scenarios, the query is executed without error in Oracle PL/SQL Developer.

The following code is from my PHP search function. The input data to this function is an associate array of field names and the user inputted search criteria data for that field.

```
     public function Search()
     {
        if($this->dbcon)
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ship_request ";
            $postCount = count($this->post_data);
            $counter = 0;

            if ($postCount > 0) 
            {
                $query .= "WHERE ";
            }

            foreach ($this->post_data as $k => $v)
            {
                $counter++;
                if (strlen($v) > 0)
                {
                    if ($k == 'SR_DATE') 
                    {
                        $query .= $k . " = :" . $k . " AND ";
                    } else {
                        $query .= "upper(" . $k . ") like upper(:" . $k . ") AND ";
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (substr($query,-4) == "AND ")
            {
                $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 4);
            }

            $stid = oci_parse($this->ifsdb, $query);

             foreach ($this->post_data as $k => $v)
            {
                if (strlen($v) > 0)
                {
                    if ($k == 'SR_DATE') 
                    {
                        $this->post_data[$k] = date("d-M-y", strtotime($this->post_data[$k]));
                        $placeHolder = $this->post_data[$k];
                    } else {
                        $placeHolder = '%' . $this->post_data[$k] . '%';

                    }
                    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $k, $placeHolder);
                }
            }
            oci_execute($stid);
            $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $recordsFound);
            $recordsFound = json_encode($recordsFound);
            oci_free_statement($stid);
            echo $recordsFound;
        } else {
            die("Could not connect to database!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've done a var_dump on $query to see what my query actually looks like when I enter multiple search criteria values. This is an example of what I see:

`select * from HOL_SHIP_REQUEST where upper(sr_shipper_name) like upper(:sr_shipper_name) and upper(sr_recipient_name) like upper(:sr_recipient_name) and sr_recipient_phone like upper(:sr_recipient_phone)`

That query returns 0 records when I enter "a" for Shipper Name, "m" for Recipient Name, and "2" for Phone Number.

This query, when executed in Oracle PL/SQL Developer, however, returns 27 records.

`select * from HOL_SHIP_REQUEST where upper(sr_shipper_name) like upper('%a%') and upper(sr_recipient_name) like upper('%m%') and sr_recipient_phone like upper('%2%')`

Is there something wrong with the way that I'm trying to bind the parameters in PHP? Is there something different I have to do when using multiple `like` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten the `%` wildcard chars in your built query string. The DB interface libraries do NOT parse the query you're building, and do NOT look for `LIKE` clauses - it's not their job to guess what kind of  match you're trying to do. e.g. are you doing

```
WHERE a LIKE 'b'
WHERE a LIKE 'b%'
WHERE a LIKE '%b'
WHERE a LIKE '%b%'
```

It's up to you to provide the appropriate wildcards, and since you're using placeholders, you'll have to do it yourself, e.g.

```
WHERE UPPER(sr_shipper_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', :sr_shipper_name, '%')
```

If you were to do it something like this:

```
$shipper = '%foo%';

WHERE  ... LIKE :shipper
```

you'd end up with the equivalent of:

```
WHERE ... LIKE '\%foo\%'
```

The placeholder system also doesn't parse your provided text and try to figure out if you're really trying to use a wilcard or just passing in a literal `%` char. That's why you have to use the `CONCAT` hack to build a proper wildcarded construct.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You are right - I was forgetting the wildcard chars. However, when I attempted to fix this function by using `CONCAT` as well as `||` between the arguments, I still had the same results. Accurate results returned in PHP when using one search criteria/LIKE statement, records that did not match the search criteria when using two search criteria/LIKE statements in PHP, and zero records returned when using three or more search criteria/LIKE statements.

Comment: you are using `AND` for your various like clauses, so  if they're ALL tied together with and, the only records you'll get where ALL of the clauses had a match. You probably want `OR` instead, where you'll get results even if ONE field matches.

Comment: You're right about the `OR` part - it does make more sense to do the search this way. I'm still not getting the correct results when comparing my queries between PHP and Oracle PL/SQL Developer, though. Interestingly enough, the query results are correct when I use a directly comparison (e.g. `SR_RECIPIENT_COMPANY = :sr_recipient_company`), but I really want to use wildcards (unless there is a better way that you may be able to suggest).

Comment: might want to look into using fulltext indexes instead, though I've never deal with oracle for that, so no idea what its capabilities are like for that.